# What is the best way to modify a UILocalNotification after it has fired?

Tags: ios, alert, uilocalnotification

I understand that you cannot modify a UILocalNotification after it has been scheduled. My problem is that I want to set the .repeatInterval so that it fires at a specific time once per day. However I want the content to change every day. So the user sets the alarm to fire at 10AM, and every day at 10AM gets an alert with different content without having to reset their alarm.

I was thinking about canceling and rescheduling when didReceiveLocalNotification was called but that requires the user to launch the app before the next scheduled alert. Is there a way to call a method immediately after the alert is fired?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you have no certain way of knowing that a local notification has fired unless your app is frontmost at the time it fires.

And, as you say, you cannot change a notification.

So I think your best bet is do *not* use repeating notifications. Set up a *different* single notification for each day, say, two weeks ahead, with different messages for each, and hope the user runs the app between now and then so that you can "refresh" the queue, as it were. Maybe make only the last one repeating, just in case, so that the notifications never stop - but of course then the message will be same each time. But there's nothing you can do about that. You can't force the user to run the app.

Comment: Thanks matt, I am thinking I might have to go that route. If so though I think the best thing to do will be to set the reminders for 2 weeks ahead. and then have each one repeat every 2 weeks. That way at least if they don't reopen they can recycle 14 messages instead of just 1 repeating.

Comment: That is a very good compromise. So then when your app next launches, you can look around and see what date and time it is, and see if you need to revise the queue.

Comment: Is there a way I can call a method in my Viewcontroller from my app delegate (say didReceiveLocalNotification or didBecomeActive)? That way I could update the alerts when the app opens but Im not sure how to call methods from the VC in the app delegate.

Comment: Yes, of course, but you might not need to. There is an applicationDidBecomeActive notification, for example. So just register for that notification in your view controller and presto, it is called whenever your app becomes  active. But make sure this is a view controller that will always exist!